# Printing the Child Number After Fork()

Tags: c, unix, operating-system

I am reading a book about Operating Systems and am fairly new to C programming as well (tends to complicate things) but am curious as to why I cannot print the incremented i value when every child is created via the fork(). Does it lie with the child processes or something else? Thanks in advance.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>

int main ()
{
    pid_t pid;
    int i = 1;

    pid = fork();
    pid = fork();
    pid = fork();
    pid = fork();

    if (pid == 0) {
        printf("got child %d\n", i);
        i++;
    }
}
```

Comment: What are you expecting this to output? What does it output?

Comment: I wanted to see the amount of children spawned. And I think im understanding why it wont work this way now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't print an incremented value because `i` is not being printed after being incremented. The processes spun off by `fork()` don't share resources, they each get an independent copy of `i`. So you'll see:

```
got child 1
```

over and over. Try this tweak and you'll see that each of the child processes are getting in to the conditional with the same value:

```
int main () {
  pid_t pid;
  int i = 1;
  pid = fork();
  pid = fork();
  pid = fork();
  pid = fork();
  if (pid == 0) {
     printf("the child %d, got %d\n", getpid(), i);
     i++;
  }
}
```

Comment: This actually answers my question, thank you.

Answer (score 2):

use `getpid()` and `getppid()` for parent and child process ids.

Example is [here](http://www.dailyfreecode.com/code/fork-child-print-process-id-parent-2179.aspx)

```
int main()
{

        int i;
        printf("hello before fork \n");
        printf("i : %d\n",i);

        i=fork();
        printf("\n");

        if(i==0)
        {

                printf("Child has started\n\n");
                printf("child printing first time \n");

                printf("getpid : %d getppid : %d \n",getpid(),getppid());
                sleep(5);
                printf("\nchild printing second time \n");
                printf("getpid : %d getppid : %d \n",getpid(),getppid());
        }
        else
        {
                printf("parent has started\n");
                printf("getpid : %d  getppid : %d \n",getpid(),getppid());
                printf("\n");

        }

        printf("Hi after fork i : %d\n",i);

        return 0;


}
```

> Output:
>
> [04mca8@LINTEL pp]$ ./a.out hello before fork i : 134514088
>
> Child has started
>
> child printing first time getpid : 8354 getppid : 8353
>
> parent has started getpid : 8353  getppid : 5656
>
> Hi after fork i : 8354 [04mca8@LINTEL pp]$ child printing second time
>   getpid : 8354 getppid : 1 Hi after fork i : 0

Comment: Thank you for helpful example link.

Answer (score 1):

Each parent/child has a separate stack for the memory, so will each get their own version of `i` that it is set to. So the `printf` will just print 1 - i.e. 16 of them.

use `getpid` and `getppid`.

Answer (score 1):

Your code doesn't make any sense at all.

1. Each call to `fork()` will create a new process at that point.
2. Each of the two processes will then continue execution at the point after the `fork()`.
3. This means that your second `fork()` will be called by *two* processes; the original one and the child created by the first `fork()`.
4. And so on.
5. You overwrite `pid` a bunch of times, and then check it for 0.
6. You print `i`, not `pid`, and increment it *after* printing it, which will have no effect.

Please study these things further, you seem to be somewhat confused.

Comment: I was asking to understand and after a few replies I think I made some headway.